# I want to do a calculator for android wear, how can i do the button click event?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, android-activity

I was using this method (the same for normal devices), but doesn't work

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });`
```

How i can do the button click?

Answer (score 0):

To create the click event of an Android button, follow next steps :

1. Open the XML file and find your button declaration.
2. Add the element "android:onClick = method-name", where "method-name" is any name you want, for example "btn_exit_click".
3. Open the java file and declare a method with the same name, example:
   "public void btn_exit_click ( View v ) { }". Pay attention to the paramenter "View v" (mandatory).

That's it. Every time you click (or tap) the button, the method will be executed.

Comment: Doesn't work, this method can be used in Android Wear?

Comment: You tagged "Eclipse", well, it works in Eclipse and NetBeans. By the way, when you say "it doesn't work", you mean nothing happens when you click the button?

Comment: Here is the reference, I have tried it and it works for me : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

Comment: No, I did it with my Samsung Galaxy, but that's why I gave you the reference from Android (Google).

Comment: ¿Puedo ver su código, Eduardo? Talvez pueda encontrar el problema.

Comment: My program is working now, i did your method. Android Wear is a bit different and i was lost, but now everything is ok. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try #2, click event on Android Wear :

1. Open your XML file and find your button.
2. Add an ID (if you don't have it already) : "android:id="@+id/buttonNotify", or any other name.
3. Open your JAVA file (the one attached to the XML file).
4. Go to top and declare a global property : private Button buttonNotify (not necessarily the same name).
5. Find (or declare if missing) method onLayoutInflated.
6. Initialize button :

> buttonNotify = (Button) findViewById( R.id.buttonNotify );
>
> buttonNotify.setOnClickListener( MyActivity.this );

7. Now, the click event method itself :

> ```
> @Override public void onClick ( View view ) {
> Intent i = new Intent( view.getContext(),MyActivity.class );
> i.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
> PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity( view.getContext(),0,i,0 );
> Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder( view.getContext() )
>                                           .setContentTitle( "Title" )
>                                           .setContentText( "Text" )
>                                           .setContentIntent( pi )
>                                           .setSmallIcon( R.drawable.ic_Launcher )
>                                           .setAutoCancel( true );
> Notification n = nb.build();
> NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
> nm.notify( NOTIFICATION_ID,n );
> }
> ```

Previous code was stolen... I mean, borrowed from :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cofoEczd5IY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YusQzqKrbRQ

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-wear-part-4-simple-notifications/

Another useful link :

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html